# Selecting properties across pipes

Tags: powershell

If I have a line like:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity what -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select ????
```

How do I select `DisplayName` and `Alias` from the `Get-Mailbox` part of the line and also the `TotalItemSize` from the `Get-MailboxStatistics` part of the line?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *calculated property*:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity what -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | 
    Select-Object DisplayName, Alias, @{l='TotalItemSize'; e={$_ | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. TotalItemSize shows up empty though.

Comment: Does `Get-Mailbox -Identity what -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics` return a TotalItemSize? I don't have the exchange module installed, just adopt your example to a calculated property.

Comment: Yeah it has a property called `TotalItemSize`